# Using the submit button to link to another page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, submit

I'm sure this is easy once you know rails but I'm new to it...

I want to redirect to another page/action after the submit button (f.submit) is pressed, and only after it is pressed. How do you determine the link that you go to after the submit button is pressed?

Answer (score 6):

Submit buttons are used to submit forms to a controller action. In the controller action you can use the `redirect_to` method to redirect to another page.

For example, let's say you have a form for creating widgets. That form would typically submit to the `create` action in the `WidgetsController`, which could redirect to a listing of widgets that would include the newly created widget:

```
class WidgetsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def create
    # Do stuff to create the Widget
    ...
    redirect_to widgets_path # Redirects to /widgets
  end
end
```